# Scalar Value Declaration Error

Tags: sql, parameters, parameter-passing

I've been trying to use the SQLcmd Parameter for my code:

```
Dim Conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(MSSQLstring)
    Conn.Open()

    Dim strUserCode = CType(Session("usrCd"), String)

    Dim SQLstring As String

    If strUserCode = "ADMIN" Then
        SQLstring = "SELECT COUNT(AskAOID) AS credits, CatCode AS category, ProductCode " _
                                & "FROM dbo.AskAO_Stats " _
                                & "WHERE (FirstResponse BETWEEN @dateFrom; AND @dateTo;) " _
                                & "AND (Status='ACTIVE' OR Status='CLOSED') " _
                                & "AND (FirstResponse IS NOT NULL) AND (CatCode IS NOT NULL) AND (ProductCode IS NOT NULL) " _
                                & "GROUP BY ProductCode, CatCode " _
                                & "ORDER BY CatCode"
    Else
        SQLstring = "SELECT COUNT(AskAOID) AS credits, CatCode AS category, ProductCode " _
                                & "FROM dbo.AskAO_Stats " _
                                & "WHERE (FirstResponse BETWEEN @dateFrom; AND @dateTo;) " _
                                & "AND (Status='ACTIVE' OR Status='CLOSED') " _
                                & "AND (Deferred = '" & strUserCode & "') " _
                                & "AND (FirstResponse IS NOT NULL) AND (CatCode IS NOT NULL) AND (ProductCode IS NOT NULL) " _
                                & "GROUP BY ProductCode, CatCode " _
                                & "ORDER BY CatCode"
    End If

    Dim SQLcmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SQLstring, Conn)
    SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateFrom", dpFrom.SelectedDate.ToString)
    SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTo", dpTo.SelectedDate.ToString)
    Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter(SQLstring, Conn)
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    DA.Fill(DS)

    Conn.Close()
```

dpFrom and dpTo are Date Pickers and I was trying to eliminate concatination in my SQL declarations. Unfortunately, from the above code, I get this error message:

**Must declare the scalar variable "@dateFrom".**

I haven't used SQLcmd Parameter alias until now, so I would like to know what I did wrong :(

Thanks all :)

**Update**

I also tried the following code change but I had no luck :(

```
Dim Conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(MSSQLstring)
    Conn.Open()

    Dim strUserCode = CType(Session("usrCd"), String)

    Dim SQLstring As String

    If strUserCode = "ADMIN" Then
        SQLstring = "SELECT COUNT(AskAOID) AS credits, CatCode AS category, ProductCode " _
                                & "FROM dbo.AskAO_Stats " _
                                & "WHERE (FirstResponse BETWEEN @dateFrom AND @dateTo) " _
                                & "AND (Status='ACTIVE' OR Status='CLOSED') " _
                                & "AND (FirstResponse IS NOT NULL) AND (CatCode IS NOT NULL) AND (ProductCode IS NOT NULL) " _
                                & "GROUP BY ProductCode, CatCode " _
                                & "ORDER BY CatCode"
    Else
        SQLstring = "SELECT COUNT(AskAOID) AS credits, CatCode AS category, ProductCode " _
                                & "FROM dbo.AskAO_Stats " _
                                & "WHERE (FirstResponse BETWEEN @dateFrom AND @dateTo) " _
                                & "AND (Status='ACTIVE' OR Status='CLOSED') " _
                                & "AND (Deferred = '" & strUserCode & "') " _
                                & "AND (FirstResponse IS NOT NULL) AND (CatCode IS NOT NULL) AND (ProductCode IS NOT NULL) " _
                                & "GROUP BY ProductCode, CatCode " _
                                & "ORDER BY CatCode"
    End If

    Dim SQLcmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SQLstring, Conn)
    SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateFrom", dpFrom.SelectedDate)
    SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTo", dpTo.SelectedDate) 
    Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter(SQLstring, Conn)
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    DA.Fill(DS)

    Conn.Close()
```

Comment: You have a lot of issues in your code. At first you have extra semicolon after `@dateFrom` in your queries? Then you try pass the datetime as string which may caught error in conversion or wrong conversion.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan  I tried it without the semicolon, but it still didn't work :( Formerly, I tried it without the .ToString and I had the same issue :(

Comment: I am not too familiar with VB myself but i would imagine this error is caused because your not declaring the dtFrom and dtTo variables as datetimes...

Comment: I'll try that :) I saw in MSDN that you can use either SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue or SQLcmd.Parameters.Add and use SQLcmd.Parameters("@x").Value to pass value. What's the difference between the two methods? I was under the impression that the .AddWithValue automatically determines the data type or something to that effect.

Comment: but does it just determine the datatype for the VB or does it pass that to the database. If you just run your select against a DB it would fail for the same error but as i said i am not too savvy with VB